# How to make Boxplot more clear, readable and understandable?

Tags: python, jupyter, boxplot

I have a World Covid data csv file with 227 Rows (Countries) and 14 Columns (attributes as in "total cases, deaths, recovery, active cases, test...")

I am trying to create a boxplot in Jupyter, but its not giving me clarity on the output.
Below is the code I am trying -

**#Multiple Boxplot on one figure
#Set Style**

*sns.set(style='whitegrid')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

g = sns.boxplot(data=df, width=0.7)

plt.show()*

[Output_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaaDm.png)

I tried another very basic method - Its worst then previous one.

*df.plot(kind='box', vert=False);*

[Output_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGaPU.png)

Please help :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the scale of the plot. You are currently seeing that your observations for most of the columns get squeezed together to acommodate the outliers. You can do several things:

1. Use a log of the values so the scales are not that far apart.
2. You can also split up the columns into separate box plots to do analysis of them individually.

The definition of "clarity" is also important. What do you mean by clarity?

Comment: Thank you. You got it right, the scale is a problem here. But as per the requirement, I am supposed to show the entire data on single graph. But since, the plot is not giving clarity over the results (for clarity I mean, Output state of being clear), I have decided to divide the plot basis continents.